# Return different cell for last row of a UITableView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

My app uses a UITableview to display a feed of images. The API only gives so many images at once so I want the final cell in the tableview to be small cell that has a `Load More Button`. To do this I created a custom cell called `LoadMoreCell` with an identifier `LoadCell`

Using the `GetCell` method I do:

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // request a recycled cell to save memory
        FeedCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as FeedCell;

        if(indexPath.Row >= tableItems.Count)
        {
            LoadMoreCell loadCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("LoadCell") as LoadMoreCell;
            return loadCell;
        }
        //Set Date and title
        cell.SetInfo (ids[indexPath.Row], userID, tableItems [indexPath.Row]);
        cell.SetImage (images[indexPath.Row]);
        cell.parent = this.parent;
        return cell;
    }
```

This gives me a cell at the bottom with the `Load More Button`, but the cell is the same dimensions as a `FeedCell` not the smaller dimensions of a `LoadMoreCell`

Anyone know what my problem might be with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to override GetHeightForRow in your UITableViewSource

```
public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
     if (indexPath.Row >= tableItems.Count) {
           return loadMoreHeight;
     } else {
           return regularRowHeight;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewDelegate has a method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: You can return the height for the cell there.